# How to addClass and removeClass in the simplest way

Tags: jquery

What is the shortest way to toggle a hidden element by using `addClass` and `removeClass` after a certain other element has received a click event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#pps_Link").on('click', function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var pssd = $(".psSelectDD");
            if (!pssd.hasClass("db")) {
                pssd.removeClass("dn").addClass("db");
            } else if (!pssd.hasClass("dn")) {
                pssd.removeClass("db").addClass("dn")
            }
            evt.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `addClass()` and `removeClass()` seperataly , why not just use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

Like so:

```
$(".psSelectDD").toggleClass('dn db');
```

Answer (score 0):

WOW, you could the exact same thing with two lines:

```
$("#pps_Link").click(function() {
    $(".psSelectDD").toggleClass('dn db');
    return false;
});
```

[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className)

Answer (score 0):

ToggleClass should go some way as to helping you in this scenario: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

```
$(".psSelectDD").toggleClass('dn db');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with toggleClass this way:

```
$("#pps_Link").on('click', function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   var pssd = $(".psSelectDD");
   pssd.toggleClass("db dn");
   evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: O.K. now it's better though you could have join: `evt.preventDefault();` and `evt.stopPropagation();` to `return false;` which will give you my answer...

Comment: @gdoron `return false` does these two. I really never knew it.